# Is putting all "using" statements at top of file (Julia) bad?

Tags: julia

I am unfamiliar with good coding practices in Julia. Working in Jupyter notebook in python I typically put all import statements in one cell at the top of the file, which helps me easily see what the dependencies are.

Is it advisable to do the same with 'using' statements in Julia (I'm also working in Jupyter notebook for now)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should.  There is only one case I know where you might not want to do so, and that is if there is a large module that is only used under rare conditions -- for example, if you run a program that can produce a plot, or do similar optional functions with slowly loading modules, in some rare usage scenarios, but normally will never use that slow-to-load module.

Even then, you can easily wind up with errors at run time due to redefinitions of functions that have been already been run before the newly loaded module redefines them.